# How to install vue-multiselect with bower (missing "dist")

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bower-install

I am trying to install vue-multiselect (http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/) using Bower.
The command `bower install vue-multiselect#2.0.0-beta.15` does create a folder `vue-multiselect` in the `bower_components` folder.

The problem: there is no `dist` folder inside the `vue-multiselect` folder.

This folder is present in the github repository and contains the required JavaScript file `vue-multiselect.min.js`.

How do I use Bower to install vue-multiselect?

Comment: My solution has been to move from Bower to NPM.